# Is the word "am" natural here?

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

In this sentence:

> On a typical day, by 9pm I **am** done cooking.

I am not a native speaker, does it sound natural to native speakers?

Comment: I here most people say "I'm" instead of I am, but I here plenty of people just use "am"

Answer (score 1):

**I am done** like **I am finished** (frequently shortened to **I'm**) is typical conversational English.

It's possible to add any number of gerunds, as in **swimming, working, eating, sleeping** and so on.

Alternatively, you can use **have** in the place of **am**, generally shortened to **I've**. The meaning is the same. But with **have**, you can finish with a noun/noun phrase as well:

> I've done the rest of the work.
>   I've done everything myself.

Comment: And there's no preposition involved? Also non-native, I'm tempted to say "I'm done _with_ cooking"